# Merge statement error in SQL Server 2008 (Incorrect syntax near)

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

I'm trying to use "MERGE" in two temporary tables, I failed to get results.

Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

```
    Create Table #tmp1
    (
    [Server] varchar(4),
    [DateTime] datetime,
    IdComponent int,
    AvgTimeTaken int
    )

    Create Table #tmp2
    (
    [Server] varchar(4),
    [DateTime] datetime,
    IdComponent int,
    AvgTimeTaken int
    )

    insert into #tmp1 values ('BE01','2012-08-01 00:00:00',1,100)
    insert into #tmp1 values ('BE02','2012-08-01 00:00:00',2,100)
    insert into #tmp1 values ('BE03','2012-08-01 00:00:00',3,100)
    insert into #tmp1 values ('BE04','2012-08-01 00:00:00',4,100)
    insert into #tmp1 values ('BE05','2012-08-01 00:00:00',5,100)


    insert into #tmp2 values ('BE01','2012-08-01 00:00:00',1,100)
    insert into #tmp2 values ('BE02','2012-08-01 00:00:00',2,200)
    insert into #tmp2 values ('BE03','2012-08-01 00:00:00',3,300)
    insert into #tmp2 values ('BE04','2012-08-01 01:00:00',4,400)
    insert into #tmp2 values ('BE05','2012-08-01 02:00:00',5,500)

    MERGE #tmp1 AS [Target]
    USING #tmp2 AS [Source]
    ON ([Target].[Server] = [Source].[Server] 
        AND [Target].[DateTime] =  [Source].[DateTime] 
        AND [Target].[IdComponent] = [Source].[IdComponent])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE
        SET [Target].AvgTimeTaken = [Source].AvgTimeTaken
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT ([Target].[Server], [Target].[DateTime], [Target].IdComponent, [Target].AvgTimeTaken)
VALUES ([Source].[Server], [Source].[DateTime], [Source].IdComponent, [Source].AvgTimeTaken);
```

I'm not sure I can be wrong. At the end also has a semicolon.
Help please!

Comment: Also put semi-colons on the statements *preceding* `MERGE`. You should be in the habit of always properly terminating statements in T-SQL - these requirements are increasing with each new version, and eventually will be required everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this error before and it was because SQL Server 2008 R2 does not support the merge syntax unless you set the compatibility mode by executing the following:

**ALTER DATABASE** *mydatabase* **SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100**

Where *mydatabase* is the name of the database you want to apply this to.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the `Target` aliases in the `INSERT` clause.

```
Create Table #tmp1 (
    [Server] varchar(4),
    [DateTime] datetime,
    IdComponent int,
    AvgTimeTaken int
);

Create Table #tmp2 (
    [Server] varchar(4),
    [DateTime] datetime,
    IdComponent int,
    AvgTimeTaken int
);

insert into #tmp1 values ('BE01','2012-08-01 00:00:00',1,100);
insert into #tmp1 values ('BE02','2012-08-01 00:00:00',2,100);
insert into #tmp1 values ('BE03','2012-08-01 00:00:00',3,100);
insert into #tmp1 values ('BE04','2012-08-01 00:00:00',4,100);
insert into #tmp1 values ('BE05','2012-08-01 00:00:00',5,100);


insert into #tmp2 values ('BE01','2012-08-01 00:00:00',1,100);
insert into #tmp2 values ('BE02','2012-08-01 00:00:00',2,200);
insert into #tmp2 values ('BE03','2012-08-01 00:00:00',3,300);
insert into #tmp2 values ('BE04','2012-08-01 01:00:00',4,400);
insert into #tmp2 values ('BE05','2012-08-01 02:00:00',5,500);

MERGE #tmp1 AS Target
USING #tmp2 AS Source
ON (Target.Server = Source.Server 
    AND Target.DateTime =  Source.DateTime 
    AND Target.IdComponent = Source.IdComponent)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET Target.AvgTimeTaken = Source.AvgTimeTaken
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT (Server, DateTime, IdComponent, AvgTimeTaken)
VALUES (Source.Server, Source.DateTime, Source.IdComponent, Source.AvgTimeTaken);
```

Answer (score 0):

The insert column list used in the MERGE statement cannot contain multi-part identifiers. Use single part identifiers instead.